# Find record of last 12 month in rails 2.3.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to find all records of table of last 12 month.

Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I just dont get it why -1? :(

Comment: don't worry +1.. no problems in this question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have class `ModelName` that inherits from `ActiveRecord::Base`:

```
ModelName.all(:conditions => ['created_at > ?', Time.now - 12.months])
```